# SQL, get top 2 rows and turn fields into columns

Tags: sql, multiple-columns

I am trying to complete what to me is a complex query and am a little stuck. 
I am returning several rows but I only want the first 2 rows and I need to turn the ItemNum column into two columns Item1 & Item2
So I have a result set that looks like this. THe Data source will have 1 - any number of rows for each email and Category.

```
Email           Category ItemCount  Date                    ItemNum
jimbo@GMAIL.COM CASE FANS   3       2013-07-16 00:00:00.0   11-999-344
jimbo@GMAIL.COM CASE FANS   3       2013-07-16 00:00:00.0   35-103-178
jimbo@GMAIL.COM CASE FANS   3       2013-07-16 00:00:00.0   35-129-060
miyaa@YAHOO.COM CASE FANS   4       2013-07-16 00:00:00.0   35-146-003
miyaa@YAHOO.COM CASE FANS   4       2013-07-16 00:00:00.0   35-146-017
miyaa@YAHOO.COM CASE FANS   4       2013-07-16 00:00:00.0   35-146-017
miyaa@YAHOO.COM CASE FANS   4       2013-07-16 00:00:00.0   35-146-017
```

I would love to have the results look like this

```
Email           Category    Date                    Item1         Item2
jimbo@GMAIL.COM CASE FANS   2013-07-16 00:00:00.0   11-999-344    35-103-178  
miyaa@GMAIL.COM CASE FANS   2013-07-16 00:00:00.0   11-999-344    35-103-178
```

So to add to the frustration, I am not able to use TempTables or Declare any varibales.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
select a1.email, a1.itemNum, 
(select distinct a3.itemNum
    from myTable a3
    where a3.email = a1.email
    and a3.itemNum > a1.itemNum
    and not exists(
        select 'x' from myTable a4
        where a4.email = a3.email
        and a4.itemNum > a1.itemNum
        and a4.itemNum < a3.itemNum)
)
from myTable a1
where not exists
(select 'x' from myTable a2
where a2.email = a1.email
and a2.itemNum < a1.itemNum)
```

I assume your field discrimination is email (the same for several rows) and itemNum.

You can change the criteria about existing condition.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
;WITH Ranked AS 
(
    select  Email, Category, ItemNum, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY  Email, Category ORDER BY ItemCount, Date) AS RowNo
    from MyTable
)
, TopFirst AS 
(
    SELECT Email, Category, ItemNum, RowNo
    FROM Ranked
    WHERE RowNo = 1
)
, TopSecond AS 
(
    SELECT Email, Category, ItemNum, RowNo
    FROM Ranked
    WHERE RowNo = 2
)
SELECT TopFirst.Email, TopFirst.Category, TopFirst.ItemNum AS Item1, ISNULL(TopSecond.RowNo, '')
FROM TopFirst
LEFT OUTER JOIN TopSecond ON TopFirst.Email = TopSecond.Email AND  TopFirst.Category  =  TopSecond.Category
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the database you're using, you could try adding the following into your SELECT statement (I'm unable to test against your code, so this will probably need tinkering):

```
SELECT email OVER(PARTITION BY email, ItemNum ORDER BY email) as EmailPartition
```

This doesn't solve the issue of adding in columns for each item, but is a viable option for sorting out your email list and selecting a DISTINCT email/ItemNum list. This in combination with Joe Taras' answer should produce an efficient query.